# Nominatim Reverse Geocode address in Thai Characters display incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, openstreetmap, json, nominatim

I have these codes in PHP to do reverse geocode[get address from latitude, longtitude]:

```
<?php

$lon = 100.753;
$lat = 13.69362;

$addr = getAddress($lat,$lon);

echo "Address: ".$addr;

function getAddress($RG_Lat,$RG_Lon)
{
  $json = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=".$RG_Lat."&lon=".$RG_Lon."&zoom=27&addressdetails=1";
  $jsonfile = file_get_contents($json);
  $RG_array = json_decode($jsonfile,true);

  foreach ($RG_array as $name => $value)
  {
      if($name == "display_name")
      {
          $RG_address = $value;
          break;
      }
  }

  return $RG_address;
}
?>
```

The result is a string like this:

```
Short term parking, à¸—à¹ˆà¸²à¸­à¸²à¸à¸²à¸¨à¸¢à¸²à¸™à¸ªà¸¸à¸§à¸£à¸£à¸“à¸ à¸¹à¸¡à¸´, à¸ªà¸¡à¸¸à¸—à¸£à¸›à¸£à¸²à¸à¸²à¸£, à¸ˆà¸±à¸‡à¸«à¸§à¸±à¸”à¸ªà¸¡à¸¸à¸—à¸£à¸›à¸£à¸²à¸à¸²à¸£, à¸£à¸²à¸Šà¸­à¸²à¸“à¸²à¸ˆà¸±à¸à¸£à¹„à¸—à¸¢
```

I saved this string into mysql database with the field type to store this is utf8_general_ci.

My question is how can I display this string correctly in Thai Characters on web after taken it out from database?

FYI, the actual address in Thai Character is like this:

```
Short term parking, ท่าอากาศยานสุวรรณภูมิ, Samut Prakan, Samut Prakan Province, Thailand
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you store the wrong string in the first place because you didn't decode it correctly. If you take a look at the [query result in your browser](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=13.69362&lon=100.753&zoom=27&addressdetails=1) you can see that the result contains unicode escape sequences like *\u0e17\u0e48\u0e32\u0e2d*. These sequences have to be decoded first. If you enter them into a web converter like http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ you will start seeing the correct characters. You will have to perform a similar conversion *before* storing the string in your database.